# Breaking a large module into smaller ones while passing the closure

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures

I have a module like this.

```
//a require block
const requires = require('requires');
let envSpecificVar = ""

// env specific variable set
if(envCheck()){
    envSpecificVar = "env"
}

module.exports = function(Model){
    Model.func1 = function(data,cb){
    //do some things
    }

    Model.func2 = function(data,cb){
    //do some things
    }

    Model.func3 = function(data,cb){
    //do some things
    }
}
```

Now I want to break this into multiple files. Which I did like this:

index.js

```
module.exports = function(Model){
    require('./func1').call(this,Model);
    require('./func2').call(this,Model);
}
```

fun1.js

```
module.exports = function (Model) {
    Model.func1 = function (data, cb) {
        //do some things
    }
}
```

And so on. And I am calling it like

```
const bFiles = require('./brokenFiles');
.
.
bFiles.call(this, Model);
```

But I know that I am only passing the `this` context and cannot access the closure.

But I want to exactly do that. Because there are weird env variables that are set in the main js file. **(which I cannot change)**

This is a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Feel free to ask for more information or mark it as duplicate.

Comment: Where are you using `this`?

Comment: What is the `Model` that you are passing, and how do you try to access the closure?

Comment: I am not using `this` that much, but passed `this` if in future some developer decides to use it.

Comment: It's using Loopback, so what loopback does is, executes all the `Model` functions passing a `Model` inside inside and stores it in `app.Models` object. `Model` has functions like find, findOne

Comment: So what is the problem with `this`? What are you trying to access, from where, that you can't?

Comment: the problem is not `this` the problem is I want to access `envSpecificVar` from the sub modules.

Comment: Oh, it finally sunk in! No, of course you can't access `envSpecificVar` when you don't define the functions in its scope. You will need to pass the value explicitly to your functions, like you already do with `Model`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create another module containing all the configurations:

```
  module.exports = { 
    envSpecificVar: ""
  };
```

Then you can import that from all the other modules.

Comment: Yes. I tried do that but

As I said I cannot change the existing code. because the code is managed by 100s of developers. And I only can like duplicate the initialisation part of the main JS file in all of my sub modules. can you think of any other things?

Comment: Global variables?